# Jquery toggle switch gives null on document ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, toggleswitch

Hi Im using jquery ui toggleswitch [toggleswitch.js](https://github.com/jamiebicknell/Toggle-Switch/blob/master/example.html)

how can i get on /off  value on document ready

i'm using this code  on document ready

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     alert($('.ui-state-active').html());
   }
```

it gives null but when i use firebug console and run it gives value of on/off by running this code below.

```
$('.ui-state-active').html()
```

there is not much documentation of this widget
 can anybody help?

Comment: Where is toggleswitch.js included? That plugin is adding `.ui-state-active` after DOM ready (which happens early).

Comment: Where is the code that initializes the plugin..?

Comment: There probably *is* a better solution, but more information is required to help provide one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you run your code before  plugin did it's job (also started at ready), first check if .ui-state-active esxist, if not run timeout and try again

```js
function checkState() {
  if ($('.ui-state-active').lenght) {
    alert($('.ui-state-active').html());
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      checkState()
    }, 500);

  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

      checkState();
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: While it's likely you are correct, this is more a comment than an answer. Best you add a code example of what you suggest. :)